# Übersetzung von "to waitlist"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

> Felix was waitlisted by Yale.

Hier ist [**waitlist**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/waitlist) als Verb verwendet. Gibt es auch ein Äquivalent auf Deutsch? Oder muss man einfach nur umschreiben, wie

> Felix war auf die Warteliste von Yale gestellt.

?

Comment: Nein, aus einem Nomen ein Verb zu machen ist im Deutschen nicht so ohne weiteres möglich. Man muss das idR wohl umschreiben.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[To waitlist](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=waitlist&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)   ist schwer direkt zu übersetzen. Gebräuchlicher ist

> Felix wurde auf die Warteliste von Yale gesetzt.